# Why the here-strings in bash are slower than piping the input to a command?

Tags: bash, pipe, benchmarking, echo, stdin

I compared the execution time for unix here-strings and pipe data input to `bc`:

**pipe**

```
time for i in {1..1000}
  do
    echo "sqrt(5.09)" | bc -q > /dev/null
  done


real    0m3.584s
user    0m0.899s
sys     0m2.404s
```

vs

**here-strings**

```
time for i in {1..1000}
  do
    bc -q <<< "sqrt(5.09)" > /dev/null
  done

real    0m5.137s
user    0m0.686s
sys     0m2.262s
```

(these values are average: tested for many times)

So the `real` execution time with using here-strings is bigger then using the pipes,
but the sum of the `user` + `sys` times is still less in the case of here-strings as I initially expected (echo ... | is executed in a new process, so there is an execution overhead). Why such a strange behaviour of bash?